# How to change eth0 MAC address only using a text editor?

Tags: network-interface, embedded, openwrt, mac-address

I am running OpenWrt (=Busybox per SSH) so my amount of binaries is limited. I would like to change my MAC address only using a text editor like nano.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/basic-networking#options_valid_for_all_protocol_types), you should add the option `macaddr` in `/etc/config/network` in your desired interface.

For example:

```
config interface 'lan'
     option ifname 'eth0.1'
     option proto 'dhcp'
     option macaddr 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx'
```

After that, restart the network service with `/etc/init.d/network restart` or reboot the device.